# How do I start debugging in MonoDevelop?

Tags: windows, debugging, mono, monodevelop

I'm trying to use a "Run/Start Debugging" menu command, but whatever I do it just starts application without debugging. Can't break program execution, breakpoints are never hit.
Any explanation how to do it properly?

Answer (score 0):

Is your solution/project in a path in which any symlink is involved? If yes, try to move it to a canonical path, I've detected debugger bugs around these circumstances.

EDIT: Oh, I see you're using Windows. Well, the .NET debugger is not that good in Windows. Monodevelop is more of a replacement of an IDE for Mac and Linux, in Windows the recommended thing is to use Visual Studio or SharpDevelop.

Comment: Is it possible to debug Mono apps using VS?

Comment: what do you mean by "mono" apps? apps that run in Mono are .NET apps, mono is just a different runtime that also works on Linux/Mac

Comment: Applications running under Mono. Sincerely yours, Captain Obvious.

Comment: "debug Mono apps using VS" is very ambiguous: you could more likely mean doing remote debugging of a Mono app running in Linux/Mac, which used to be possible via "Mono Tools for VS" product (which was sold by Novell but is not sold anymore by neither Xamarin nor Novell); because there's no really value in debugging an app in Mono for Windows, as Mono in this platform is far behind in regards of features, performance, etc.

Comment: Remote debugging would be nice. But I haven't had any success with Mono Tools. Debugee process is just crashing.

Comment: I said that Mono Tools was discontinued a long time ago. Use Mono in Mac/Linux and debug there.